# For any $a\in\mathbb{N}$ $x_m=\max \{ x_m | x_m \in A, x_m < a \}$: help me decipher my calculus notes.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Our calculus lectures are messy and obscure (and so are my notes), and I need help understanding what I wrote:

> $\forall a\in\mathbb{N} \: \: \: \; \; x_m=\max\{x_m | x_m\in A, x_m<a\}$

- It is a corollary from 'Every subset of natural numbers is either finite or countable' theorem
- the set of $x_m$s is an image of bijection between naturals and a countable subset of naturals ($A$ is that subset)
- there is supposed to be a proof of this, and mine begins with 'assume the contrary: let there be such $b$ that $x_m<b<a$, then $x_{m+1} \leq b$'. (I don't understand what's happening).
- other corollaries are that every next $x_m$ in the bijection is strictly greater than the previous one, and that $m \leq x_m$

I think the statement lacks something. What could $m, a$ stand for?
I tried assuming $m, a$ to be random naturals, but then say $1 \mapsto 2, 2 \mapsto 4, 3 \mapsto 6$ and so on, $a=5, m=3$, then we have $x_3=max\{2, 4\}=4$, which is plain wrong.

Thank you.

Comment: There are a lot of $x_m$'s in your definition...are you using the object you are trying to define?

Comment: @user190080 Seems like it. Now the line $\forall a\in\mathbb{N} \: \: \: \; \; x_m=\max\{x_m | x_m\in A, x_m<a\}$ makes no sense to me. There must be a typo somewhere, but I can't pinpoint the location.